# How to emphasize the importance of a title in an article in text mining?

Tags: machine-learning, data-mining, text-mining

Using a bag-of-words approach in text mining seems the simplest thing to do and is yet most widely used.
But when using bag-of-words you can't emphasize that some part in the text is more important than the other.
In my case I have a title and a summary for each example to work with.
I want to emphasize that the words in the title and the summary are not of the same importance, therefore I can't just concatenate the strings and build a TF.IDF matrix on them.

Would building two separate TF.IDF matrices for the title and summary separately and then concatenating them be the most sensible solution to this. What else can I attempt to do?

Answer (score 1):

Why don't you just add more weight to the words in the title?

You are working with frequencies anyway, not with binary variables.

Comment: Because I don't know how much more weight should be given to those words. I don't even know if the title should have more weight. My goal is just to take both into account independently.